# How to connect to MS SQL Server with JDBC in java EE WebApplication

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I am trying to connect to local SQL server (Windows Authentication) from my first Java EE WebApplication.

From tutorials I managed to create this

```
private static Connection con;

@Resource(name = "java:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource")
private static SQLServerDataSource ds;

public static boolean Connect(String dbName){

    String conStrUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-UF0PE6E\\SQLEXPRESS:57411;integratedSecurity=true;databaseName=" +dbName;

    try {
        
        ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setURL(conStrUrl);
        con = ds.getConnection();
        
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //..printStack
        return false;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        //..printStack
        return false;
    }
}
```

I Have downloaded jdbc jar (mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre11.jar)
[downloaded Jar File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBebb.png)

I have added dependency for it (hopefully correctly)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.0.jre11</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I get this error:

```
26-Nov-2021 17:17:45.679 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.handleRenderException Error Rendering View[/helloWorld.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /helloWorld.xhtml: Error reading [s1] on type [com.journaldev.jsf.helloworld.HelloWorld]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDataSource
    at com.journaldev.jsf.helloworld.DataLayer.DbConnect.Connect(DbConnect.java:34)
    at com.journaldev.jsf.helloworld.HelloWorld.getS1(HelloWorld.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:168)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:150)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
    ... 46 more
```

I have tried conecting with DriverManager it also doesn't work for me.

Additional Info:

- using InteliJ IDEA
- integrated Maven
- Tomcat 9.0.55

Could someone tell me what steps I should take to connect with JDBC in Java EE WebApp?

Comment: Isnthe Driver in your classpath? (in the pom file)

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource` would suggest the driver is not on the classpath. Have you checked if it is actually included in the WEB-INF/lib of your WAR?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have the library as external library (see the picture in the link)

Comment: If you're using Maven to build, and if you're using a war project type, then the library should be automatically included in the `WEB-INF/lib` of the generated WAR. If that is not the case, then that is the problem. If you're not using Maven to build the WAR, then you should, or you need to configure whatever you're using to ensure the library ends up in the `WEB-INF/lib`.